# How to set properties on a Tomcat application specific?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a tomcat service with a single application, and set the following property in `setenv.bat`:

`set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.profiles.active=production`

This uses `spring-boot` and ensures the application always runs in production profile mode.

Problem: I now want to drop a 2nd application in that should not run in production. How could I configure the java opts application specific?

Is that possible at all? Or would I have to create a 2nd tomcat instance?

Comment: I would argue you are probably doing it wrong if you're trying to run both prod and non-prod inside the same JVM (which, without much knowledge of Spring profiles, appears to be the case).

I don't think it's possible to set system properties on a per app basis.

Answer (score 2):

The **JAVA_OPTS** variable is used by Java in the creation of the Java virtual Machine (the real process) so you can't told Java to create in one process 2 different processes.

I think the only solution will be to duplicate the web server (quite easy with most of them) and (having care of the ports !biggest problem!) running a second JVM for developing.

hope it helps